# Elasticsearch date histogram for earliest timestamp by distinct value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index where each document is an event in a physical city. The documents contain a bunch of information about the event, as well as the timestamp that the event occurred.
i.e.

```
[{
  "host_city": "denver",
  "timestamp":" "2019-08-26T07:10:07Z",
  "other_meta": 123
},
{
  "host_city": "denver",
  "timestamp":" "2019-08-24T07:13:17Z",
  "other_meta": 123
},
{
  "host_city": "washington",
  "timestamp":" "2019-05-21T09:10:00Z",
  "other_meta": 123
},
```

All cities have multiple events, but for the purposes of this question I am only interested in when they hosted their *first ever* event.

I need to create a date histogram showing (per day) the number of cities that hosted their first event in the last 30 days. If a city has held an event in the last 30 days, but has hosted any event at any time previous to that, they should be excluded from the histogram - I'm trying to show only *completely new cities*
i.e.

- 1/2/2019: 50 cities held their first event
- 1/3/2019: 16 cities held their first event
  *etc.

I'm currently migrating from solr to ES so don't have example code to show. At the moment I'm doing a huge amount of preproccessing to achieve this: I maintain a separate index for the first time I saw an event in each city, and add a new document to this when I see a completely new city. Then I do a basic histogram aggregation on this separate index.

I would love to be able to calculate this histogram on the fly from my raw event documents - is this possible in elasticsearch? What type of query would I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is pretty straight forward using the new [Data Frames](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/ml-dataframes.html) transformation built into 7.3 (it's a paid feature), which will build you a derivative, city-oriented index.

Using data frames, you'd define a job to group by by `host_city` and aggregate by minimum `timestamp`

```
PUT _data_frame/transforms/first-appearance-dataframe
{
  "description": "Track the first appearance data of all host cities"
  "source": {
    "index": [
      "my-source-index*"
    ],
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "city-first-appearances"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "userid": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "host_city"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "first_timestamp": {
        "min": {
          "field": "timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, it's a simple date histogram to get what you want

```
GET city-first-appearances/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "new-cities": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "first-timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data frames can be set to run continuously by passing a `sync` parameter when creating the job, so would be up to date each time you ran the histogram agg.

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks like a "cumulative" cardinality aggregation, maybe coming in 7.4, might be a one-step approach to this: [github/elastic][add cumulative and/or incremental cardinality date histogram](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/43550)